# custom UIToolbar without using background image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitoolbar

I want to make uitoolbar to have separation like this one. But i do not want to use it as background image.

any idea how to do it?

This one is only three section, and if it has four section of course the column will become have four section.

[image: UIToolbar]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 buttons instead of toolbar and for separation you can adjust the frame of buttons accordingly. Give it a try. This will look like toolbar.